# Setting up a new EPiServer 6 project with source control

Tags: episerver

I want to end up with a single VS project/solution that I can check in to source control, that any other developer in the office can simply check out and run, and that I can deploy without having to install EPiServer program files on every web server.

I have just used the EPiServer 6 Deployment center (part of the official EPiServer 6 download). That gave me an EPiServer templates project, website setup in IIS, and a database installed.

The first issue is that when I change the VS project file to use the Visual Studio Development Server, the cms start page (site centre) no longer works.

And an even bigger problem is that the **episerver.config file is using all sorts of files in the  C:\Program Files (x86)\EPiServer directory** on my machine.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539172/what-are-the-steps-to-creating-a-new-episerver-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the virtualPath items pointing to Program Files in the config file and copy those folders to the same paths inside the source controlled project folder.